# How can I restart the steps in flutter_intro?

Tags: flutter

How can I restart the steps in flutter_intro?

I tried `Intro.of(context).start();` but it only works once after the code is built.

Comment: Could you show your code? Where are you using `Intro.of(context).start();`?

Answer (score 0):

this may solve your problem but if it does not, plz share more details:
if you want to restart the steps use `reset()` before `start()` like this:

```
 final yourKey = GlobalKey<IntroState>();
....
....
....

Intro(
        key: yourKey,
        steps: [
          //  your steps 
        ],
      ),
....
....

{
  yourKey.currentState.reset();
  Intro.of(context).start();

}
```

happy coding...